# Create single map image from two images with different color tables

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

Is it possible to merge the color tables of two images when using gdal to create a single image? Or is there another way to merge said images not using a color table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use gdalbuildvrt to mosaisc the two images, then you have the possibility to set a colortable with the vrt. You can then create a color table and use a look up table  (LUT) if necessary, e.g.

> ColorTable: This element is parent to a set of Entry elements defining
>   the entries in a color table. Currently only RGBA color tables are
>   supported with c1 being red, c2 being green, c3 being blue and c4
>   being alpha. The entries are ordered and will be assumed to start from
>   color table entry 0.

```
<ColorTable>   
<Entry c1="0" c2="0" c3="0" c4="255"/>   
<Entry c1="145" c2="78" c3="224" c4="255"/> 
</ColorTable>
```

alternatively, you can use gdal_dem to set a new color table.